# AWS Lambda Function To DynamoDB - Sending Map And SS Attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I am looking to send JSON via Postman to the API Gateway API Endpoint, and am having difficulty with sending `Map` and `SS` attributes.

I have chosen `Map` for `"Created"`, and `"Last Modified"` to show the date and time.

I have chosen `SS` for list items, e.g. `"Ages": ["Grade 8","Grade 9","Grade 10"]`.

Please could someone help review the Lambda function, and JSON, to understand how to send data across? I am very new to AWS.

This will be a form for people to post jobs via a front-end.

**Lambda Function**

```
"use strict";
require("dotenv").config();
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-west-1" });
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const addJobListing = async (data) => {
  const body = {
    Item: {
      PK: data["Item"]["PK"],
      SK: data["Item"]["SK"],
      "Days Off": data["Item"]["Days Off"],
      "Start Date": data["Item"]["Start Date"],
      "Job ID": data["Item"]["Job ID"],
      "Contract Length": data["Item"]["Contract Length"],
      "Expiration Date": data["Item"]["Expiration Date"],
      Created: {
        date: data["Item"]["Created Date"],
        time: data["Item"]["Created Time"],
      },
      Insurance: data["Item"]["Insurance"],
      Title: data["Item"]["Title"],
      Holidays: data["Item"]["Holidays"],
      Ages: data["Item"]["Ages"], //NEEDS TO BE MAPPED
      "Flight Reimbursement": data["Item"]["Flight Reimbursement"],
      Curriculum: data["Item"]["Curriculum"], //NEEDS TO BE MAPPED
      "Account ID": data["Item"]["Account ID"],
      "Minimum Monthly Salary Before Tax":
        data["Item"]["Minimum Monthly Salary Before Tax"],
      "Housing Allowance": data["Item"]["Housing Allowance"],
      Responsibilities: data["Item"]["Responsibilities"],
      "Job Closest Metro": data["Item"]["Job Closest Metro"],
      "Job Requirements": data["Item"]["Job Requirements"],
      "Job Type": data["Item"]["Job Type"],
      "Z-VISA Reimbursement": data["Item"]["Z-VISA Reimbursement"],
      Meals: data["Item"]["Meals"],
      Subject: data["Item"]["Subject"],
      "Salary Information": data["Item"]["Salary Information"],
      "Maximum Monthly Salary Before Tax":
        data["Item"]["Maximum Monthly Salary Before Tax"],
      "Vacancy Status": data["Item"]["Vacancy Status"],
      "Contract Completion Bonus": data["Item"]["Contract Completion Bonus"],
      "Last Modified": {
        date: data["Item"]["Modified Date"],
        time: data["Item"]["Modified Time"],
      },
    },
    TableName: "XXXX",
  };

  return await documentClient
    .put(body)
    .promise()
    .then((data) => console.log(data.Attributes))
    .catch(console.error);
};

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("EVENT BODY", event.body);
  const response = await addJobListing(JSON.parse(event.body));
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // Required for CORS support to work
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(response),
  };
};
```

**JSON Test Via Postman:**

```
{
    "Item": {
        "PK": "ACC#1000",
        "SK": "JOBID#01.17/01/2022",
        "Days Off": "Weekends",
      "Start Date": "17/09/2022",
      "Job ID": "01",
      "Contract Length": "Two Years",
      "Expiration Date": "17/09/2022",
      "Created": {
            "date": "17/09/2022",
            "time": "00:00:00"
      },
      "Insurance": "Insurance",
      "Title": "Title Of Vacancy",
      "Holidays": "Amount of Holidays",
      "Ages": ["Grade 8","Grade 9","Grade 10"],
      "Flight Reimbursement": "Flight Reimbursement",
      "Curriculum": ["Schools Own Curriculum","International Baccalaureate","GCSE"],
      "Account ID": "10",
      "Minimum Monthly Salary Before Tax": "Minimum Monthly Salary Before Tax",
      "Housing Allowance":"Housing Allowance",
      "Responsibilities": "Responsibilities",
      "Job Closest Metro": "Job Closest Metro",
      "Job Requirements": "Job Requirements",
      "Job Type": "Job Type",
      "Z-VISA Reimbursement": "Z-VISA Reimbursement",
      "Meals": "Meals",
      "Subject": "Subject",
      "Salary Information": "Salary Information",
      "Maximum Monthly Salary Before Tax": "Maximum Monthly Salary Before Tax",
      "Vacancy Status": "Vacancy Status",
      "Contract Completion Bonus": "Contract Completion Bonus",
      "Last Modified": {
            "date": "17/09/2022",
            "time": "00:00:00"
      }
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you add any error messages you're getting to your question? Generally, to be able to answer a question, it's best to put it in the form of "when I try X, I expect Y, but what I see is Z"

Answer (score 1):

**Initial Problem:**

The issue was with the `"Created"/"Last Modified"` key/value pairs.

For Example this does not work, as it references `"Created Date"` and `"Created Time"` columns, which do not exist in the DynamoDB table:

```
  Created: {
    date: data["Item"]["Created Date"],
    time: data["Item"]["Created Time"],
  },
```

**Solution:**

Instead, `"Created"/"Last Modified"` should look like this:

```
  Created: data["Item"]["Created"],
  "Last Modified": data["Item"]["Last Modified"],
```

The "Created" can now be changed to a string too, or passed in the modified map attribute in `JSON`:

```
"Created": "2014-09-12T19:34:29Z",
```

**Tip:**
When going on DynamoDB, one can add an item and click `JSON` to see how it would look as a `JSON` item.